# How to color code fullcalendar events based on description

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, gcal

We use one calendar for the entire company that show's who has the day off. HR would like to use Blue for anyone who is in the Software department, Red for the Electronics Department and Green for the Hardware Department for the events background color.

The previous developer used FullCalendar1.5.3 and Google Calendar for this. HR would specify what person is in what department by putting S, E, or H in google calendar description. The previous developer wrote a custome code to read that description and create the event with the correct background Color. Due to the Nov 27th 2014 google v2 being shutdown, I had to re-create it using the latest fullcalendar.js and gcal.js libraries which shoes it was pretty much re-written to be able to use the google API stuff.

I got the calendar to work and show the events, but I have no idea how to make it read the description for the letters and change the bgcolor according to it's description. Does anyone have any idea how to do this, maybe using a simple switch case, or if statements?

Comment: show some code of what you have tried that isn't working.  look at using `eventRender` callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `eventRender`(callback) for this. Check for the `description` text and change the `bgcolor` for the event that you want to.

```
eventRender: function( event, element, view ) { 
     if (event.description == "x") {
         //apply your logic here, make changes to element.
         element.css('background', 'red');
     }
}
```

For further assistance [check fullcalendar docs here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)

Comment: how can you debug to know what is inside the "event.description"?

Comment: I had faced the same issue and now it has worked fine for me. Thankx a Lot!

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Franky! I was able to make create it,

```js
eventRender: function (event, element) {
   if (event.description == "(S)") { //SOFTWARE DEPARTMENT
    element.css('background-color', '#00FF00');
   } else if (event.description == "(E)") { // ELECTRONICS DEPARTMENT
    element.css('background-color', '#0000FF'); 
   } else if (event.description == "(J)") { // JP
    element.css('background-color', '#FF0000');
   } else if (event.description == "(H)") { // HARDWARE DEPARTMENT
    element.css('background-color', '#FFFF00');
   } else if (event.description == "(A)") { // ADMIN DEPARTMENT
    element.css('background-color', '#FF00FF');
   } else { // ANYONE ELSE NOT IN EITHER OF THE DEPARTMENTS ABOVE
    element.css('background-color', '#000000');
   }
  },
```

Comment: how can you debug to know what is inside the "event.description"?

Comment: console.log(event);